# Change array of object to array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have below array:

```
Array
(
    [utype_id] => 1
    [username] => admin
    [policy] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalCount] => 7
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalCount] => 1
                    [status] => 2
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [totalCount] => 5
                    [status] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

I'm getting the above array from **$returnDtls["policy"]**. Now I want to convert this array with the below:

```
Array
(
    [utype_id] => 1
    [username] => admin
    [policy] => Array
        (
               [1] => 7
               [2] => 1
               [3] => 5

        )

)
```

I'm in a big trouble with this. I have tried this with the below code:-

```
            $arr = array();
        foreach($returnDtls["policy"] as $key=>$val)
        {
            $arr[$val["status"]] = $val["totalCount"];
        }
            $data = array_merge($data,$arr);
```

But not succeed. It's giving me below error:-

**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D:\xampp\htdocs\tristar\application\modules\manage\controllers\dashboard.php on line 53**

Does anybody help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long try , I'm able to do this by myself. So I'm putting my answer by myself. Please check below:-

```
            $arr = array();
        foreach($returnDtls["policy"] as $key=>$val)
        {
            $arr["policy"][$val->status] = $val->totalCount;
        }

        $data = array_merge($data,$arr);
```

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk yes You were right. that was my first requirement. Then the requirement has changed so I also changed the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array['policy'] as $object) {
    $result[$object->status] = $object->totalCount;
}
$array['policy'] = $result;
```

Check result on [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/UZSIsX0z);

Comment: if I consider Your answer then it's giving proper output with object array. But I'm getting below error:- Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D:\xampp\htdocs\tristar\application\modules\manage\views\dashboard.php on line 5

Comment: and Alexander Yancharuk , I haven't change question just for matching my answer. depending on project requirement - I have to change the requirement.

Comment: ok, look at updated answer.

Comment: Yes. the updated answer also working

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr['policy']); $i++){
    $arr['policy'][$i+1] = $arr['policy'][$i]['totalCount'];
}
```

Comment: yes , but "policy" element may hold more than 3 elements. Because I'm getting this array from dynamic output.

Comment: first of all , I'm doing it in php. Second, in my array it contains "array of object". So I can't use this. It will give me fatal error. But thanks for Your reply.

Comment: I didn't see the PHP tag at begin. Let me change the code for PHP